# Singleton execution for multiple application requests with persession WCF service object

Tags: c#, singleton

I have one class (Concurrency) object in which i am initiating all db related settings .
All this code is in WCF service. For instance management, i have made service instance on persession basis. Now i want to share Concurrency class object through all db layer classes. I was thinking to do this singleton can be used.Though i have used persession instance creation for wcf service, i am confused , how singleton pattern will react for multiple requests at same time. Will each user get same class object or same class object will be shared with all users ?

Scenario  is : I have **user** object. **User belongs to organisation**. WCF service have method '**UserRegistration**'. with wcf service , i have separate class library for db operations. When any client calls user registration method, in Concurrency object i have to set **db settings against user's organisation** . For this i want to manage one Concurrency object per user. Is it right way to do?

Comment: the `Concurrency` object is exposed via a WCF service and you want to depend on it in your DB access layer? sounds like a potentially bad idea. Could you share some code so we can see the structure you want as an outcome?

Comment: I am not going to share Concurrency object via WCF. please read question again.. i have made some changes to clear actual scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope understand your question correctly. I had this issue myself with a single entry point for our DAL. It had to work on multiple platforms: WCF, WF, ASMX, ASP.NET, etc.

I came up with this implementation of singleton that saves the class instance in the user session, when applicable for that platform:

```
public static Class1 Current
{
    get
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null) /* ASP.NET / ASMX / ASHX */
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Class1"] == null)
                HttpContext.Current.Session["Class1"] = new Class1();

            return (Class1)HttpContext.Current.Session["Class1"];
        }
        else if (OperationContext.Current != null) /* WCF */
        {
            if (WcfInstanceContext.Current["Class1"] == null)
                WcfInstanceContext.Current["Class1"] = new Class1();

            return (Class1)WcfInstanceContext.Current["Class1"];
        }
        else /* WPF / WF / Single instance applications */
        {
            if (Class1.current == null)
                Class1.current = new Class1();

            return Class1.current;
        }
    }
}
```

If you have multiple objects in your layer, you could refactor this away in a base class or method.

Comment: Thanks for reply... Above code is going to work in WCF project . right? actually i want to manage all db operations & instance creations in db layer only... My project contents are : WCF application, Application service(class library), Domain service(class lib.)  Infrastructure Service(class library). Now  i want to keep wcf service service & application service layer for pure function calls & returning required values. In domain service i wan to initiate my 'Concurrency'  class object as it will be used to initiate my different domain related class objects

Comment: That's all fine. This works on multiple platforms, also on WCF, without the need to adapt the code every time.

Comment: @user3759078: Since you are new: if your question has been answered and you have no further questions, please accept the answer you liked best by checking the checkmark before the answer.